# Avoid code duplication in XACML

Tags: xacml

**Description**

I have created multiple XACML files containing several policies which are evaluated according the `first-applicable` rule-combining-algorithm.

Sometimes I am unable to avoid code duplication in XACML and I have to copy a certain XACML policy at several locations in the XACML file.

Is it possible to avoid code duplication in XACML via e.g. `<import file="xacml/deny-policy.xacml"/>` like in xml or via another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually there is already way to refer already existing policies inside another policy for reusability.
You may use either of the two ways:

1. Using Policy Id reference : Call existing policy inside another policy/PolicySet.
2. Using Policy Set id reference : Call exisitng PolicySet inside another policySet

For example below is the way to call an existing policy inside another policy:

### Existing policy "policy1" to be resued:

```
<Policy PolicyId="policy1" ....>
....
....
</Policy>
```

### Call "policy1" inside another policy:

```
<Policy PolicyId="MasterPolicy" ....>
<Description>Master Policy Set</Description>
<Target>
  ....
</Target>

<PolicyIdReference>policy1</PolicyIdReference>

</Policy>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have tried to implement this in our software, but it is not working. I have checked the OASIS XACML 2.0 and 3.0 documentation and the `PolicyIdReference` and `PolicySetIdReference` elements are required. A bug has been filed for our software in order to fix this and to implement XACML according the standard. I am convinced that the implementation of `PolicyIdReference` and `PolicySetIdReference` elements in our software are a convenient way for us and our customers to avoid code duplication in XACML. I will let you know the outcome if the bug has been solved.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Yusuf said, you can also use variable definitions. Variable definitions are expressions you can define inside policies and which you can reuse inside rule conditions.

See the XACML [specification](http://docs.oasis-open.org/xacml/3.0/xacml-3.0-core-spec-os-en.html#_Toc325047128) for more details.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have checked this in our software and it is not implemented, while it is required according the XACML 2.0 and 3.0 standard. I have filed a bug for this. I am convinced that the use of `VariableDefinition` and `VariableReference` will avoid code duplication in XACML. I estimate that it will be slightly more difficult for our customers to avoid code duplication in XACML than via `PolicyIdReference` and `PolicySetIdReference` but it is interesting to implement and these elements are required according the standard.